# Overboarding thickness - how much smaller will my room be?

Tags: drywall, wallpaper

I have a lot of woodchip wallpaper and normal wallpaper, all painted over multiple times. Removing it is going to be hell.

So instead I was thinking of overboarding, but how much room will I lose to that? Some of the corridors are only 1m wide.

Presumably I'll need to put up trusses, screwed into the brickwork, and then plasterboard over those. Plasterboard is 10-13mm thick, plus say 10mm for the truss, on both sides, which suggests the corridor would end up being about 950mm wide at the end, not too bad.

Is that a reasonable assumption or will it be thicker than that?

This is a residential house in the UK. There will be wiring behind the plasterboard, i.e. through the trusses.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.  You seem to ask how much space will I lose but then you go ahead and answer it yourself.

Comment: Is it a room or hallway/corridor that you're working on? Is it a commercial or residential space? What does your local building code say about minimum dimensions, especially in regards to fire egress?

Comment: I'm asking if my assumptions are correct. I have edited the question for you. This is a residential space.

Answer (score 2):

- 10 mm "truss" + 13 mm plasterboard (taking the high end) = 23 mm
- 23 mm x 2 (both sides) = 46 mm
- 10000 mm wide corridor - 46 mm = 964 mm

Your estimate of 950mm of remaining space seems reasonable.

Other than checking your math, I'm not sure what else we can tell you or what your real question is.

Comment: Thanks. So a 10mm truss is reasonable for this kind of thing? Will it be okay with wiring etc. ?

Comment: @user I have no idea. 10mm = ~0.4". I don't know where you're going to get any wood that thin unless you're ripping sheets of plywood into strips. I have no idea what kind of wiring you're going to put under there. I had no idea whatsoever you were going to add wiring between the existing wall and this new inner wall. That was _not_ part of your original question, and, frankly, supports my comment question of what are you trying to accomplish. Your question is so vague that it's almost impossible to answer beyond simply checking your math, which I've done.

Comment: BTW- _mentioning_ that you're going to put wiring in _may_ be helpful, but _asking_ whether this is suitable will change your question and make it too broad.